# Is it possible to get only changed data with query observe in ObjectBox?

Tags: android, objectbox

I was reading the [doc](http://objectbox.io/documentation/data-observers-reactive-extensions/) about observing queries.

```
Query<Task> query = taskBox.query().equal(Task_.completed, false).build();
subscription = query.subscribe().observer(data -> updateUi(data));
```

From what i understand , this code returns all the data every time. but for RecyclerView add/remove animation to work, we need to know which data is changed and we need to know what kind of change is happened to data (remove/change/add).

is there anyway to get changed data only?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a responsibility of ObjectBox to define a change. There is [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) that responsible for that in android. If you google that you can find tons of examples (e.g. [sample](https://proandroiddev.com/diffutil-is-a-must-797502bc1149)). The only advice there is to put DiffUtil payload to background thread if your list contains lots of items or items are fat(contain dozens of fields).